# How to reference a Web Service from an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I want to add a web service to my `ASP.NET MVC 5` project.

I do that by right click on the project in solution explorer > `add` > `service reference`.

Then I add a web service url like [this](http://www.ibanbic.be/IBANBIC.asmx) and it creates a new file in `Service References` folder called `ServiceReference1`

Then I'm able to call web service methods in C# by using `ServiceReference1` namespace and VS intellisense works.

The problem is that when I add [this](http://merchant.parspal.com/WebService.asmx?wsdl) web service url, it adds a new namespace (`ServiceReference2`) to that folder, but I can't call the new namespace and it says `ServiceReference2 namespace could not be found`.

Is it me doing something wrong or the web service has a problem?

Comment: You're doing it the right way. It could be a problem with the service. Notice that the first one works but the second one does not, so the issue must be with the difference between the services.

Comment: Your first link goes to an .asmx. Your second one goes to the wsdl of the .asmx. Is it that simple?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you open your service window, click on the advanced button like below.

In general, I agree it's best not to use the older versions of web-services like I'm showing here, but in real life people have deadlines and such.

Saying that though, there is no huge drawback to using this tech, as long as performance isn't an issue.

[image]

Then, click 'add Web Reference' like the picture below.

[image]

Then enter URL and click on the little arrow button.  Name your reference and click 'Add Reference'.  see pic below

[image]

Comment: You're going straight to web references without knowing what the problem is

Comment: I agree with @JohnSaunders. You should not work around issues by taking a step back in time.

Comment: Thanks. web reference is older than web service, but it works anyway.. I'll have to stick with this since the service provider is not responsible cc/ @JohnSaunders

Comment: You should find out _why_ service reference isn't working for you, rather than punting and using a legacy technology which is far less capable.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  - Any suggestion for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34090045/2404470)